What's a classic (paper) example in which OLS gives unreasonable result, but IV estimate gives reasonable result?
I'm wondering are there are any classic papers, especially in the field of labor economics or development economics, that include regression tables showing OLS gives unreasonable result(like regression sign opposite to theoretical prediction), but IV estimate gives reasonable result? It would be great if you could recommend a few of such papers with links. Thanks in advance.
